# How to forbid bluetooth file transfer in centos?

Tags: centos, bluetooth

My company uses Centos 6.5 for our destop OS. My boss wants to avoid information leaks.
I already forbid usbdisk in Centos, but somebody uses Bluetooth to transfer files.
At the same time, some guys need Bluetooth because they use Bluetooth keyboards.
Then, how can I forbid Bluetooth file transfers but can still connect Bluetooth keyboard in Centos?

Comment: This is a policy and Human Resources problem, not a technical one. If you are unable to trust your employees, they should not be working for you. Likewise, if you have policy forbidding copying files to external devices, and you've found a person that violated this policy, then terminate that employee. No matter what technical countermeasures you put in place, untrustworthy employees will always be able to find a way to get what they want.

Comment: @EEAA This is all true enough, as far as it goes, but it doesn't mean that we just stop using security controls altogether.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Certainly. I wasn't trying to presume that nothing technical *should* be done, rather just trying to emphasize that this is not something that is able to be completely solved with technical means.

Comment: @EEAA Actualy in most it companies, lots of technical methods used to avoid information leak.let's back to technical question itself.

Comment: I looked into this a bit. It will be _much_ easier to disable Bluetooth entirely and buy everyone new keyboards...

Comment: The wireless keyboards could easily be considered a risk as well if you're that stringent...